# Date format changing on RTL devices?

Tags: android, right-to-left

I have a date field that is presented great on LTR devices (android 7.1.1)
The issue is that on RTL devices the date field content is mirrored

So on US devices the date will appear normally : **03/14/2019**
On RTL android devices the date will appear like so: **2019/14/03**

Code for the TextView holding the value:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inspect_date"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.xerox.printerinspection.controls.DateEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_inspect_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:drawableEnd="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am setting the date like so:

```
   Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
   inspectionDateEdit.setDate(currentDate);
```

What will be the correct way to fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

Parent  fragment_detail.xml tag looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/lightGray"
    android:textDirection="locale"
    tools:context="com.xerox.MainActivity">
```

Comment: So you want same **03/14/2019** for both the localization. correct?

Comment: yes, same 03/14/2019 for both the localization or at least to be able to control the format.

Comment: could you please post code for `inspectionDateEdit.setDate(currentDate);.`

Answer (score 6):

Due to the parent's `android:textDirection="locale"` attribute (which might even be the default value, when having set `android:supportsRtl="true"` in the `Manifest.xml` - and could therefore be omitted), one has to define the text-direction for the nested child node - so it won't inherit the parent's value; this at least works for an `EditText`, when forcing `RTL` layout on a `LTR` device:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_inspect_date"
    android:text="@string/edit_inspect_date"
    android:textDirection="ltr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image: screenshot]

Possibly the `android:drawableEnd` should be `android:drawableRight`, so that it would not be affected (this depends upon, if it is intended to have it flipped to the other side, whether or or not).

Comment: While the source of the issue is correct, I would suggest a different value for textDirection... "anyRtl" for example.

Comment: @Raanan [anyRtl](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) is exactly what is not intended (at least how I've understood the problem). Sadly I could not find any documentation for the `com.xerox.printerinspection.controls.DateEditText` component ...because setting a reverse date-format string there might also be an option.

Comment: I disagree, I posted my reasoning in Answer.

Comment: @Raanan how should it be better than forcing `LTR`? there won't be any `RTL` characters... or do `RTL` languages have different date-formats (opposite than expected in the OP)? We'll see what is the preferred outcome ...while admittedly, my understanding is limited to Arabic numbers.

Comment: Yes, some RTL languages have date formats which don't use Latin letters like Farsi and aren't LTR. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Iran

Comment: @Raanan for a proper solution, such special cases should be taken care of... while one still can supply format-strings with string resources.

Comment: IMO, Using content aware direction settings like I suggested should handle most special cases. And also some simple cases like mixing RTL and LTR text in the same page.

Comment: @Raanan it might merely depend upon, which formats this `com.xerox.printerinspection.controls.DateEditText` supports... it seems to be some proprietary library, which does not seem to be publicly available.

Comment: I agree. My suggestion is a more higher level solution to `RTL` layout text direction issues. I also haven't tested it for this specific case, which might require your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You simply can format the Date to the form what you want and don't worry about it, like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String dateFormat = format.format(YourDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, identify if the layout direction is Right to Left or not.

```
boolean isRightToLeft =
  TextUtilsCompat.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) ==
  ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL;
```

if it is, then just reverse the date format yourself,

```
SimpleDateFormat format;
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
if (isRightToLeft) {
  // yup, use the mirrored date format
  format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/dd/MM");
} else {
  // use the regular date format
  format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
currentDate.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(currentDate)));
inspectionDateEdit.setDate(currentDate);
```

At run time, os will then mirror your `yyyy/dd/MM` to `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this form

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining the layout direction as `ltr` for the DateEditText in the xml file.

Comment: I have android:textDirection="locale", so layout direction is set by locale.

Comment: I'm saying you should overwrite this particular DateEditText's direction as ltr, so that it's always ltr, regardless of the locale.

Comment: You said you have `android:textDirection="locale"` but it is not displayed in your question. Is it for parent layout?

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code with both localization. I have tried with both localization and it works fine.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String currnetDateString = df.format(currentDate);
yourTextView.setText(currnetDateString);
```

**Update:**

As you told, if you are using inspectionDateEdit as DatePicker, you can use it like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String currnetDateString = sdf.format(currentDate);
try {
  Date currentDate2 = sdf.parse(currnetDateString);
  inspectionDateEdit.setDate(currentDate2);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: inspectionDateEdit is a date picker

Comment: Rumit, why Locale.US and not device Locale?

Comment: @user648026 Because that is what causing the problem. `Locale.US` will keep date in English and formatted. If we have device locale **i.e.** `Locale.getDefault()` , It'll take automatically default locale. and turns it to *2019/14/03*.

Comment: formatting using SimpleDateFormat is working fine.. 
but displaying that is not correct.... it mirrors the date....

Comment: Have you checked it with `TextView` also? try my upper code to `TextView` and check.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to [change the parent `android:textDirection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) to `anyRTL`:

> *"`anyRtl`    -   The paragraph direction is RTL if it contains any strong RTL character, otherwise it is LTR if it contains any strong LTR characters. If there are neither, the paragraph direction is the view’s resolved layout direction.
>   "*

Reason is if you set Text Direction to a specific one LTR or RTL directly or by device locale (as you did) you might encounter the same issue when trying to add a LTR text in the middle of a RTL page or vice versa. i.e. a comment in English in the middle of a full RTL page. 
A better approach IMO is to use `anyRTL` which will decides by the content what is the right direction.

For your specific case a Date in Latin numbers is always LTR.